# How can I reduce the top margin of an <hr /> element?

Tags: html, css

My code is like this :

```
<div class="right">
    <div style="padding-left: 40mm;"> 
        <table>
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr style="max-width: 40mm; margin-right:0 height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">
</div>
```

I want to reduce the space between `hr` and `div` tag

I have tried like below

```
<hr style="max-width: 40mm; margin-right:0 height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;margin-top:-10px !important">
```

But it does not work. How can I solve it?

Update Fiddle is below

https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/qgr0u3wb/

In the above fiddle, I want reduce the space between `hr` and `<div class='test'>`

Comment: It may be that you have a margin on the `div` itself from a CSS stylesheet, or the content of the table could be affecting it. With so little information and no fiddle, it's hard to tell.

Comment: use `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BRYpNm I just used `margin: 0` so it would be beside the text, but you just need to remove the vertical margins.

Comment: @fubar, I had update my question

Comment: You're missing semi-colons between each style property declaration. https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/qgr0u3wb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
hr {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color:#333;
  max-width: 40mm;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
    <div style="padding-left: 40mm;"> 
        <table>
            ... Here's your answer
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```